# react: короткая запись import с использованием файлов из подпапок

Tags: reactjs, typescript, проектирование, организация

Подскажите можно ли реализовать следующее:

В react проекте есть папка 'mypanel' внутри которой лежат файлы:

```
mypanel.tsx
interfaces.tsx
styles.css
```

внутри `mypanel.tsx` лежит компонент `MyPanel`

Сейчас вызов MyPanel из какого-то внешнего относительно `mypanel` файла выглядит так:

```
import MyPanel from '../mypanel/mypanel'
```

Но хотелось бы запись сократить ибо она избыточная до

```
import MyPanel from '../mypanel
```

для чего в папке `mypanel` вроде как надо было добавить файл `index.ts` в котором и вызвать `import  'mypanel.tsx'`

Но что-то не выходит.

Подскажите как корректно это сделать.

P.S.

организовал структуру проекта в таком виде - каждый компонент находиться в отдельной папке, которая содержит файлы с описанием компонента, стилей и интерфейсы данных, используемые в компоненте

или такая организация не очень хорошая?

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте в index.ts писать

```
export * from './mypanel.tsx';
```

Comment: да, строка сработала
но компонент `MyPanel` не подхватился - выдается ошибка на строке `import MyPanel from '../mypanel'` :(

Answer (score 0):

помог такой подход:

в `index.ts` вписать

```
import MyPanel from './mypanel'
export default MyPanel
```

не знаю насколько корректен такой подход, но он работает

P.S.

хотелось бы больше универсальности и меньше строчек кода